# How to terminate idle instances using ASG or lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, instance, amazon-cloudwatch

We are having multiple test servers which are running idle and needs to terminate/stop to reduce cost
Scenario is we are using Jenkins to run a project where developers will build the project and everytime new server will spin up, if there is any stopped server due to the previous build it will first terminate the stopped one and then new instance will spin up.
I tried using

1. Cloudwatch CPU utilization function to stop/terminate idle instances but as every time a new instance ID will generate this option is out.
2. We are using ASG, but when I tried using simple step scaling to reduce it to zero it didn't work

I am looking to create lambda function so idle instance will stop/terminate without considering instance ID

Comment: Please read tag descriptions.  The python-idle tag is for the IDLE IDE that is part of the Python stdlib.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for the inputs. But now I used the lambda function to stop the server on a scheduled basis with cron job

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.